# Bulma: how to make buttons the same size?

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm using Bulma css and would like to make buttons the same size. Currently, each button has different size depending on the button title.
The only options I'm finding is "is-fullwidth", but that's too big.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. What is preventing you from simply using custom CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write as many column elements as you may need, inside a `columns` class element. Then put one button inside each `column` element with the `is-fullwidth` class.

```
 <div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-2">
       <button class="button is-outline is-primary is-fullwidth" id="acceptBtn">Ok</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-2">
       <button class="button is-outline is-secondary is-fullwidth ml-5" id="cancelBtn">Discard changes</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

In this example I put only two buttons, but they can be as many as you need.

The `column` elements will set the width and the button class `is-fullwidth` will expand the button to the available width of its container.

If you want this solution with less verbose code, try this:

```
<div class="columns">
   <button class="button is-outline is-primary is-fullwidth column is-2" id="acceptBtn">Ok</button>
   <button class="button is-outline is-secondary is-fullwidth ml-5 column is-2" id="cancelBtn">Discard changes</button>
</div>
```

Adding the `is-fullwidth column is-2` classes directly to a `<button>` is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with bulma classes (except for the `is-fullwidth` one), but you could make your own global class that you can add to buttons. e.g.:

```css
.button.is-wide {
   min-width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Bulma already provides classes to achieve that. Check my answer.